# Access DB connected with local directory

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

Basically I want the connection of my Access DB always available, so if i move the folder project to another computer it has to keep working, without changing the folder path.
I'm working with Windows Forms in Visual Studio 2012.

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source= Z:\Tempesta\Area Progetto\Area_Progetto_27_02_2014\Area_Progetto_DATA_MAGAZINE\Data_Magazine\Data_Magazine\DB\DataMG.mdb";
```

That's the code I have right now for the connection to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data
>   Source=|DataDirectory|DataMG.mdb"